# Angular arrange and save user modified template

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

using angular one to show some data from database, for example:
field-1 field-2 field-3 field-4
i had on default template, but now added second, it works fine.

```
<div ng-show="isUserLogedin" ng-include="'header.htm'"></div>
<div class="div_content">
    <div ng-hide="isUserLogedin" ng-include="'login.htm'"></div>

        <div ng-show="isOTHER"   ng-include="'filter.htm'" onload="finishLoading()"></div>
        <div ng-show="isadmin"  ng-include="'filteradmin.htm'" onload="finishLoadingadmin()"></div>

       </div>
```

This logic works but every time some group needs to change field location, i have to change it manually, is there any way to make in angular 1 something like drag and paste location of fields, save it into cookies or in DB and show each user his own template?
this is how looks like part of filter.htm

```
<table class="contentTable" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><a href="#" ng-click="changeOrder('Field_1');">field_1</a></th>
               <th><a href="#" ng-click="changeOrder('Field_2');">field_2</a></th>
                <th><a href="#" ng-click="changeOrder('Field_3');">field_3</a></th>
               <th><a href="#" ng-click="changeOrder('Field_4');">field_4</a></th>



            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="main_container_right_div1">
            <tr dir-paginate="item in serverData | itemsPerPage: itemPerPageValue | orderBy : orderBy ">
                <td>{{ item.field_1 }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.field_2 }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.field_3 }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.field_4 }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found This post but can't figure out how to save modified template and show it next time user logins
https://marceljuenemann.github.io/angular-drag-and-drop-lists/demo/#/nested